# Is it OK to place an other user's video on my page?

Tags: ranking, video, youtube

My idea is to take my article and add a video best describing my topic in the bottom of the page.

My thought is this will enhance my visitors experience, make stays on the page longer an therefore better ranking and more pages to be visited by a user.

The reason I want to use another person's video is that I simply don't have one. Filming a quality video content requires a lot of effort and skills I don't have.

I read Youtube standard licence and come to the conclusion that I'm not restricted to do so. But I think that it will be more polite to put a link to owner channel, which will drive more traffic to him or her.

So my questions are:

1. Am I correct that this will really improve my traffic quantity and quality?
2. Is that correct that I will not do any violations doing so?
3. Is it OK to skip asking permission from video owner?
4. Any other thoughts on the topic?

Comment: By "place in your page" do you mean use youtube's embedded video widget in compliance with youtube's terms and conditions?

Comment: @stephen I did not aware of these details. I wanted the video to be watchable directly on the page. Is it "embeded video widget" you are talking about?

Comment: Yes, youtube's widget makes it playable in the page as long as the video hasn't set the setting for preventing that.    That would be opposed to copying the video, redestributing it yourself,  and playing it with a different player.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is that correct that I will not do any violations doing so [with the YouTube Standard License]?

The YouTube Standard License basically authorizes YouTube to distribute the video via its platform. Remaining rights not covered by the license are retained by the original author(s) of the video.

As @StephenOstermiller points out, YouTube's embedding widget is specifically designed for sharing via YouTube, but on a separate web page.
So using this widget to display the video on your page would be perfectly acceptable.

However, if you simply downloaded the video and embedded it in your page via another player (not YouTube's widget), you would almost certainly be running afoul of YouTube's licensing and likely general copyright law depending on where you live (since only YouTube and the original author have distribution rights).

*Note: Even with the widget, playback via another web page may be disabled. If this is the case, the widget will display a message saying so and direct viewers to the original YouTube video.*

> Is it OK to skip asking permission from video owner?

If you use YouTube's widget, yes. Even so, linking back to the author is still a nice gesture in my opinion.

The other case for not asking permission would be if the video is under a Creative Commons License (this is the other license authors can use for their work on YouTube).

Otherwise, no.

> Am I correct that this will really improve my traffic quantity and quality?

Maybe. It depends on how Google, et al. decide to treat the video.

As a for instance, certain queries in Google will bring up StackExchange listings (which do not have videos) before other results (including YouTube video tutorials).

My personal thought would be to embed the video if it enhanced the user's experience. If it gets a higher ranking, great. It is extremely unlikely to hurt your ranking in any meaningful way, regardless.